# Warn when sending mail outside of local domains

Tags: vba, outlook

I have the following code which checks if the email you are sending is within our local domain and if it isn't it will prompt you a Yes/No confirmation.

I would like to alter this to check for a few additional domains that are also internal so it does not prompt the message for these domains.

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim recips As Outlook.Recipients
Dim recip As Outlook.Recipient
Dim pa As Outlook.PropertyAccessor
Dim prompt As String
Dim strMsg As String

Const PR_SMTP_ADDRESS As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E"

Set recips = Item.Recipients
For Each recip In recips
Set pa = recip.PropertyAccessor
If InStr(LCase(pa.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS)), "@domain.com.au") = 0 Then
strMsg = strMsg & "   " & pa.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS) & vbNewLine
End If
Next
For Each recip In recips
Set pa = recip.PropertyAccessor
If InStr(LCase(pa.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS)), "@domain.com.au") = 0 Then
prompt = "This email will be sent outside of domain.com.au to:" & vbNewLine & strMsg & "Do you want to proceed?"
If MsgBox(prompt, vbYesNo + vbExclamation + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Check Address") = vbNo Then
    Cancel = True
    Exit Sub
Else
    Exit Sub
End If
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by simple AND conditional.

```
If InStr(LCase(pa.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS)), "@domain.com.au") = 0 AND InStr(LCase(pa.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS)), "@domaintwo.com.au") Then
```